# Easymock incompatible return value type error

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I'm trying to create a EasyMock for this particular piece of code, such that innerfValue is of type IJavaValue, which is a subclass of IJavaObject. I've tried conventional methods of dealing with this by mocking innerfValue and then just assuming aJavaValue points to innerfValue and mocking the sendmessage method as if it were a method of innerfValue, but its hasen't been working and by the time I get to the end it gives me a incompatible return value type when I do (symbolvalue in this case is a mock object that I made to return after the sendmessage method was called on my mock innerfValue object, not the saem as the symbolValue in the other piece of code):

```
EasyMock.expect(((IJavaObject)symbolValue).toString()).andReturn("aValue");
```

Here is the piece of code

```
IJavaObject aJavaValue = (IJavaObject)innerfValue.getValue();
IJavaObject symbolValue = (IJavaObject) ((IJavaObject)aJavaValue).sendMessage(
    "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;", null, thread, false);
value = symbolValue.toString();
```

Comment: 1) You don't need to cast in the expectation in your unit test. The mock `symbolValue` should already have a `toString` method.

Comment: 2) In what way is it now working? An "incompatible return value type": does this mean that it returns a value but not the one you want? or does it not return any value?

Comment: In my failure trace for my junit,it states "java.lang.illegalStateException: incompatible return value type". As for what the error actually is, I'm not 100% sure. I guess that's my question.

Comment: Hmm. Unsure about that. If you've got the whole stack trace, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EasyMock cannot mock the toString() method. This is why I was having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see where my problem is.

If you are using  EasyMock.createMockBuilder(XXX.class)

Make sure you remember to addMockedMethod("methodName").createMock();